# UI getting blocked in loop

Tags: swift, multithreading, loops, uibutton

So I have this problem where I need to stop a loop from occurring using a UIButton. The issue with this is that the while loop seems to prevent the UIButton from being pressed. From what I've researched you need to use a thread which is different to the one the UIButton is updating on however, as much as I've tried, I have been unsuccessful in doing this. Below is the while loop which is getting blocked and I would appreciate any help towards getting the problem solved. Thank you.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func counter() {

seconds -= 1;
label.text = String(seconds) + " Seconds"

if(seconds == 0) {

timer.invalidate()
audioPlayer.play()

while(UIScreen.main.brightness <= CGFloat(0.5)) {

UIScreen.main.brightness += 0.01;

  }
 }
}
```

And the function in which the UIButton is contained

```
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
timer.invalidate()
seconds = 30

sliderOutlet.setValue(30, animated: true)
label.text = "30 Seconds"

sliderOutlet.isHidden = false
startOutlet.isHidden = false

audioPlayer.stop()}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your while loop called?

Comment: Its called within a larger function called counter which is then called from a timer. I have updated the code above so you can see the function and the timer which calls it (excluding the function in which the timer is contained).

Comment: Have you tried using `Dispatch.async`?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used the Dispatch.async method and it works perfectly :)